# How to set jqGrid default to collapse

Tags: jqgrid

i have a working jqgrid table and I wanted the default table to collapse on load.  I have checked the site's documentation but I couldn't find the option for this.  The button is has a class `ui-icon-circle-triangle-n`.

many thanks.

Comment: Do you speak about treegrid collapsing or about the grouping collapsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once did this by calling .click() on the collapse button after loading the table. Maybe not the most robust solution, but it worked for me.

Comment: You should probably try to find a more specific selector than just ui-`.icon-circle-triangle-n` though, as that class is used for setting the background of the element. Using only that selector would fire the click event on all such elements in the document.

Answer (score 9):

hiddengrid is a property of the grid that will accomplish what you want. See the last property set in the below example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
         var grid1 = jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
             url: '/controller/action/',
             datatype: 'json',
             mtype: 'POST',
             colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2'],
             colModel: [
      { name: 'Col1', index: 'Col1', width: 22, align: 'left'},
      { name: 'Col2', index: 'Col2', width: 22, align: 'left'}
      ],
             sortname: 'Col1',
             sortorder: "asc",
             caption: 'Sample Grid',
             rowNum: 10,
             pager: '#,
             hiddengrid: true

     });
</script>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me! Other than the accepted answer, this answer will wait to trigger loading the data until you expand the grid. So I prefer this option, thank you for this hint!

Answer (score 1):

Recently I found a better solution and more efficient than trigger the click.

Just add the `groupingView` element with the `groupCollapse` option in the `gridOptions` element.

Some like that:

```
// grid options
{
   groupingView: {
       //Collapse all
       groupCollapse: true
   }
}
```